# Сдвиг таблицы истинности

Tags: функции, булева-алгебра

Имеется таблица истинности  логической функции от трех аргументов **F(A,B,C)**.

Известно что функция принимает истинное значение только для двух наборов значений аргументов, причем эти два набора расположены в таблице истинности подряд друг за другом. Комбинации значений аргументов в таблице истинности выстроены сверху вниз в лексикографическом порядке.

Далее был сдвинут столбец значений логической функции **вверх на 6 позиций** и обнаружено, что другая логическая функция **G(A,B,C)**, задаваемая получившимися после сдвига значениями, принимает истинное значение для комбинаций аргументов, каждая из которых является противоположной одной из комбинаций, для которых была истина функция **F(A,B,C)**. (противоположной - инвертированной)

Требуется найти функцию F.

Не очень понимаю, как можно определить истинность двух соседних наборов первой функции, не могли бы вы объяснить, как здесь действовать? буду очень благодарен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

6 вверх - это то же самое, что 2 вниз. Поэтому надо найти число x, такое что множества `{x&7, (x+1)&7}` и `{(x+2)&7, (x+3)&7}` содержат противоположные числа. Поскольку сдвиг на 2 не меняет последний бит, порядок надо поменять:

```
x & 7 = ~(x+3) & 7
(x+1) & 7 = ~(x+2) & 7
```

Заменим `~t & 7` на `(7-t) & 7` (модуль 8, а 8-1=7):

```
x & 7 = (7-x-3) & 7
(x+1) & 7 = (7-x-2) & 7
```

```
x & 7 = (4-x) & 7
(x+1) & 7 = (5-x) & 7
```

Избавимся от `+1`

```
x & 7 = (4-x) & 7
x & 7 = (4-x) & 7
```

Получилось одно уравнение

```
x & 7 = (4-x) & 7
```

Его решениями являются `x = 4-x` и `x == 4-x + 8`, т. е. 2 и 6.

Возвращаемся к функции:

```
f(2) = f(3) = f(0,1,0) = f(0,1,1) = 1
g(4) = g(5) = g(1,0,0) = g(1,0,1) = 1
```

```
f(6) = f(7) = f(1,1,0) = f(1,1,1) = 1
g(0) = g(1) = g(0,0,0) = g(0,0,1) = 1
```

По идее, решений 2. Но если мы вспомним оригинальное условие и уберём цикличность, то получим только второе решение.

Впрочем, если убрать цикличность, то второе решение вообще единственное потенциально возможное, поскольку единицы в любых других строках бы просто исчезли.

Так что решений всё-таки два.